# current_user_can('manage_options') causes white screen of death?

Tags: themes, fatal-error

The condition `if(current_user_can('manage_options'))` causes white screen of death, and for obvious reason I cannot track the error, and debugging didn't yield anything. I am pretty sure the condition is causing this behavior (when having `if(true)` everything works just fine). So where do I start to fix this?

If this might be helpful, I will post a plugin that contains the code (is fairly simple, used for changing a theme depending on privileges):

```
function change_theme($theme) {
    if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
        $theme = 'theme1';
    } else {
        $theme = 'theme2';
    }

    return $theme;
}
add_filter('template', 'change_theme');
add_filter('option_template', 'change_theme');
add_filter('option_stylesheet', 'change_theme');
```

Comment: You should activate the `php` error display from `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` and WordPress error display in `wp-config.php` put `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`. Does it yield now?

Comment: Thank you, setting display_errors to 1 has let me determine that for some reason wp-includes/pluggable.php was not included while running the plugin, so wp_get_current_user() function was missing. Although I didn't find the reason of malfunction, thanks to answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127559/wordpress-plugin-call-to-undefined-function-wp-get-current-user) question I hardcoded plugin by setting `if(!function_exists('wp_get_current_user')) {
    include(ABSPATH . "wp-includes/pluggable.php"); 
}`, and now everything works fine.

Comment: Glad to be of service. Include that in your question so that people know you've solved it and answer it (there is a button below)

Answer (score 2):

Setting display_errors to 1 has let me determine that for some reason wp-includes/pluggable.php was not included while running the plugin, so wp_get_current_user() function was missing. Although I didn't find the reason of malfunction, thanks to answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127559/wordpress-plugin-call-to-undefined-function-wp-get-current-user) question I hardcoded plugin by setting following at the beginning:

```
if(!function_exists('wp_get_current_user')) {
    include(ABSPATH . "wp-includes/pluggable.php");
}
```

Now everything works fine.